# node js error while running swagger project

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, node-modules, swagger-ui

I'm using swagger-ui-dist folder for my project. While I'm running it via npm run dev, it runs well and I can see the desired behaviour.

However, when I commit it to server, something gets changed and running it on server through npm run dev gives below error:

```
import path from "path";
       ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Module._compile (/Users/myuserName/Desktop/APIs_Clone/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/myuserName/Desktop/APIs_Clone/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
```

Kindly help resoling it, thanks in advance :)

Also below is my dev.babel.js file code:

```
const path = require("path");
import { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } from "webpack"
import configBuilder from "./_config-builder"
import styleConfig from "./stylesheets.babel"

const devConfig = configBuilder(
  {
    minimize: false,
    mangle: false,
    sourcemaps: true,
    includeDependencies: true,
  },
  {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
      "swagger-ui-bundle": [
        "./src/polyfills.js", // TODO: remove?
        "./src/core/index.js",
      ],
      "swagger-ui-standalone-preset": [
        "./src/polyfills", // TODO: remove?
        "./src/standalone/index.js",
      ],
      "swagger-ui": "./src/style/main.scss",
    },

    performance: {
      hints: false
    },

    output: {
      library: "[name]",
      filename: "[name].js",
      chunkFilename: "[id].js",
    },

    devServer: {
      port: 4493,
      publicPath: "/",
      disableHostCheck: true, // for development within VMs
      stats: {
        colors: true,
      },
      hot: true,
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "../", "dev-helpers"),
      host: "0.0.0.0",
    },

    plugins: [new HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  }
)

// mix in the style config's plugins and loader rules

devConfig.plugins = [...devConfig.plugins, ...styleConfig.plugins]

devConfig.module.rules = [
  ...devConfig.module.rules,
  ...styleConfig.module.rules,
]

export default devConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't support ES6 imports out of the box. [This feature is still experimental](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html)

You have 2 solutions :

- Use `require` :

```
const path = require("path");
```

- You can try to set up your project with babel, which will transpile your code to something supported by NodeJS : https://babeljs.io/en/setup

---

**Edit:**
Since your babel config file also uses the ES6 imports, you cannot start the building process of your app. So in order to use ES6 imports in your actual app code, your build scripts and configs can only use `require`.

You should replace the `import` statements in your dev.babel.js file to this :

```
const { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } = require("webpack")
const configBuilder = require("./_config-builder")
const  styleConfig = require("./stylesheets.babel")
```

Comment: Hey Seblor, Thanks for prompt response. In dev.babel.js I've changed  import path from "path" to 
const path = require("path") but still the same error.

Comment: You cannot have the same error if the source has changed. Maybe you need to rebuild, or you edited the wrong file. Also if you are already using Babel, can you add your config file in your question ?

Comment: Hi Seblor,  yes the error is changed a little. Even after rebuilding, it is not yet resolved : (  import { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } from "webpack";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Module._compile (/Users/ashish.kumar/Desktop/PayU_APIs_Clone/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/Users/myuserName/Desktop/APIs_Clone/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)

Comment: The problem causing the issue is the same. The building scripts and configs you are using to build your application (allowing it to use the ES6 modules) is already using the ES6 modules. So you need to have your build scripts / configs use only the `require` instad of `import`